# Show form validation error for User login on Modal itself- Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Although my User login is working perfectly fine but I am unable to handle User form validation on modal itself. I mean, I am able to get the user name and pwd and validate it but if the user name and pwd didn't match, the page is redirected to a Django template. But I want to show the message like `username pwd didn't match` on modal itself not on another Django template.

**Modal code**

```
<div class="modal signUpContent fade" id="ModalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center"> Login </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {% if form.errors %}
            <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if next %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
                please login with an account that has access.</p>
                {% else %}
                <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <form action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if next %}
                  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                {% endif %}
                <div class="form-group login-username">
                    <div>
                        <input name="username" id="login-user" class="form-control input" size="20" placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" value="{{ username }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group login-password">
                    <div>
                        <input name="password" id="login-password" class="form-control input" size="20" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <div class="checkbox login-remember">
                            <label>
                                <input name="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input name="submit" class="btn  btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" value="Log In" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <p class="text-center"> Not here before? <a data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" ng-href="#ModalSignup"> Sign Up. </a> <br>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" ng-href="#ModalPwdReset"> Lost your password? </a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**setting.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/index'
```

So, how to get error message on modal form itself ?

Comment: I have exact same issue and am wondering if you were ever able to fix the problem.

Comment: did you solve it ? i am here with the same issue

Comment: @Animesh, i am in the same problem, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @NestorColt: I didnt find a proper solution so I dropped the modal idea. :(

Comment: @NestorColt: Nope, still looking.

Comment: I already have the errors appearing in the modal implementing the ajax callback, but I am getting other weird error when the form is actually submitted, gonna polish the code, maybe 20 hours more reading, a liter or two of coffee and I will post the solution here @animesh for you both and others

Comment: @NestorColt: May your efforts succeed and shine light onto us! Good luck dude.

Comment: @Animesh, well, less than 20 hours, idk if this will fully adjust everybody's needs, but it is working nice and clean for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been having the same issue, I wanted to use the Django build in authentication system to make a login page for my portfolio/blog website, this means that I am not implementing custom forms/views at all for this, and I just create the view in the **url.py** directly from **django.contrib.auth.views.login** , I found a workaround that helps to my case, and maybe putting some logic in it others could find a way to adjust the idea to their projects as well, here is the code:

---

1. **urls.py** :

---

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views as view
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^coltapp/', include('coltapp.urls')),
    url(r'^$', view.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),

]
```

**Notice this line:**

```
url(r'accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
```

Here I am using the build In Django login view  - **views.login** - , so , like i said before, no custom form or views created for this pourpose.

---

2. **Base.html**

---

I am calling the modal as the bootstrap documentation recommend it, also, I am including this custom_modal.html inside of the base.html so i can use it in future operations; I have to point out that I have this on a nav-var, that's why is inside of a list item tag.

```
<li><a id="loginAnchor" data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'login' %}" data-target="#custom_modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>

{# THIS WILL INCLUDE THE MODAL CONTACT WINDOW FOR FURTHER USE #}
{% include "coltapp/custom_modal.html" %}
```

---

3. **custom_modal.html**

---

a simple .html file with JUST the logic structure for the modal to work, but nothing else inside, no extended from base **no nothing** just as you can see.

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="custom_modal" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modal-custom" >


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

In this way, i make this modal reusable, and after I will be able to inject any other data that I want inside of **modal-content div** by Ajax or whatever.

---

4. **login.html**

---

Here I managed the Rendering fields manually, I found this more practical as I have total control over each field from this form, **remember, I have no view/form code for this login view**, this **comes with Django build-in auth views**

```
<div id="login-jumbo" class="jumbotron">

    <div style="margin-bottom:1%" class="modal-header">

        <button id="login_close" type="button" class="close .login-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

        <h1>Welcome back Nestor!</h1>

    </div>

    {% if form.errors %}

        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}

            <div class="error-message">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h4>Ops! Invalid Data...</h4>
                </div>
                <ul><li><h5>{{ error|safe }}</h5></li></ul>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var divisor = document.querySelectorAll(".form-div");
            var len = divisor.length

            for (let i=0; i < len; i++  ){

                divisor[i].className += " has-error";
            }

        </script>

    {% endif %}

    <form id="login_form" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for field in form.fields  %}

            {% if field == 'username' %}

                <div class="form-group form-div">
                    <h4 class="control-label">{{ field|title }}</h4>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
                </div>

            {% else %}

                <div class="form-group form-div">
                    <h4 class="control-label">{{ field|title }}</h4>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
                </div>

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        <div style="margin-top:2%" id="login_footer" align="right" class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="login">Log In</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

**Have to note:** I've managed the errors inside of this template,
 **{% if form.errors %}** then I will call an **alert message from bootstrap**, this is really important for what I'm going to do in the next section in the JS file, also I've iterated over the fields and put them into a div in pairs, login, and password fields, and also I have made a little script that will add a class to those divs in case of errors found on form. **class='has-error'**, these error classes comes directly from bootstrap for error handling.

**- this is the data that will be rendered inside of the modal!**

---

5. **Jquery ajax request**

---

The Ajax call is very self-explained, and also there are a lot of reference on internet about this o about how they have to be implemented

```
$(document).on('submit','#login_form', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var login_form = $('#login_form');
    var action = login_form.attr('action');
    var method = login_form.attr('method');
    var data_ = login_form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: action,
        data: data_,
        success: function(data, status) {

            if ($(data).find('.alert-danger').length > 0) {
                $('.modal-custom').html(data);
                // console.log(data)

            }else{

                console.log('Log In Form Successfuly Summited')
                $('#custom_modal').modal('hide')
                location.reload(); //Reload the current document page on success

            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

going through this, you pass the necessary data to the ajax call, and **if this function is a success**, you will apply some logic:

- If find any element with **('.alert-danger')** class on it, this means that the form has some errors on it, **(you could use 'has-error' too)**, so if this condition is true, keep the modal open, and send the data again with the line:

**`$('.modal-custom').html(data);`**

**'modal-custom'** is the **inner** div from the **custom_modal.html**, where everything is rendered.

- If not errors in form, that means no **('.alert-danger')** class found on it, hide the modal, and reload the current document location, it means to reload the actual URL on the web browser, I made this because is a modal login page, sI i will need some elements to appear after the user is logged In.

also, I made to little more procs to clean the modal from errors on hiding, because if I was not logged In, and close the modal again without re-loading any page, these errors will appear again on the modal, so this was more for a cleanness procedure.

```
var restoreModalOnClose = function(){
    var error_fields = $('.has-error')
    var danger_pop = $('.alert-danger')

    danger_pop.parent().remove()

    $.each(error_fields, function(index, value){
        $(value).removeClass('has-error');
        // console.log(value)
    })

};


$('#custom_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e){
    console.log('here')
    restoreModalOnClose()
});
```

I hope this helps to anyone in the future, I been reading a lot of post, docs and etc etc, and at the end, i found a workaround what satisfied what I was looking for.

JPG reference:

[image: Login Modal form with errors]

Comment: I am using Django 3. I am getting an error in urls.py stating that module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

Answer (score 0):

You can override the *clean* method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .... # your code here

    def clean(self):
        if wrong_credentiels():
            raise ValidationError("username pwd didn't match")
```

***wrong_credentiels*** is a method where you can put in your verification logic

Comment: he is using the Django auth system to log in,**from django.contrib.auth import views** not using custom form or view, so this answer is not valid.